# Geometric interpretation of an orbit of a group action

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory

I got stuck finding the geometrical interpretation of the orbit of a group action.

The action of the group $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$ on the set $\mathbb{R^2}$ (the real plane) is given by $$a\cdot(x,y)=(x+ay,y)$$ and the orbit is $\mathbb{R} \cdot{(x_0,y_0)}$.

My instinct was this should be a horizontal line but I don't know how to prove it. As a result, I don't know how to find its stabilizer.

Can someone please enlighten me how to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $y \neq 0$, choose some point on the line and find the a that gets that point. 

If $y$ is 0, think about the orbit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the stabilizer. This is the set of all $a$ so that $a \cdot (x_0, y_0) = (x_0, y_0).$ By applying our formula, we find that this means $(x_0+ay_0, y_0) = (x_0, y_0),$ so that $ay_0 = 0.$

Thus if $y_0 = 0,$ the stabilizer is all of $\mathbb{R}$, and otherwise the stabilizer is 0.

Geometrically, you can think of the action as follows. You start at a point $(x_0, y_0),$ and then the action $a \cdot (x_0, y_0)$ is varying $(x_0, y_0)$ along the line $y=y_0$ at a velocity of $y_0.$ When $y_0=0,$ you don't move at all and so the stabilizer is everything. When $y_0\neq 0,$ since you're moving around, you only are stabilized by $a=0.$